# SF Rounded Navigation Bar Title Font in Swift

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

I am doing a test (just to learn SwiftUI) and I wanted to use SF Rounded as the navigation bar title font. But after hours of research I wasn't able find a solution.
Here are things I was able to do :
Set the font color
Set the background color
And I actually was able to use a custom font (one that is in iOS by default or course) but not the SF Rounded cause it seems to be a font "style".
And apps can use SF Rounded, I found an app on TestFlight (called Evergreen) that even has the option to change from default style to mono and rounded.
I am using SwiftUI but AppDelegate is in UIKit.

Here may be some code:

```
UINavigationBarAppearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign.rounded]
```

But setting that in AppDelegate.swift makes my app to freeze right after launch.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use SF Rounded font in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550064/how-to-use-sf-rounded-font-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

if you use:

```
UINavigationBarAppearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign.rounded]
```

It will only change the font for the title on a Navigation Bar.

What your are looking for was already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564633/8679480)

I hope that can help you!

Comment: please mark as duplicate when you see a duplicate question, don't start another thread on it.

Comment: I am sorry but I maybe wasn't clear enough but I wanted to set the "font style" as for the Navigation bar title. And I think that it just doesn't work in SwiftUI.