# How to use SF Rounded in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel

I have got a label and I spent quite a lot time trying to change the font of my UILabel to SF Rounded Bold.

Things like `titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFRounded-Bold", size: 34.0)` or `titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SanFranciscoRounded-Bold ", size: 34.0)` don't work.

Is it even possible to use SF Rounded in UIKit? It is not listed in fonts list in scene editor and no one ever asked how to use it but in SwiftUI I can use SF Rounded without any problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550064/how-to-use-sf-rounded-font-in-swiftui
There's answer from Pomme2Poule and Dan2899 that answers your question for UIKit

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 5, iOS 13+**

Here's an extension version of the other post's answer

```
import UIKit

extension UIFont {
    class func rounded(ofSize size: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
        let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: weight)
        let font: UIFont
        
        if let descriptor = systemFont.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) {
            font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: size)
        } else {
            font = systemFont
        }
        return font
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Hello world!"
label.font = .rounded(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
```

Answer (score 8):

More concise version of Kevin's answer:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIFont {
    class func rounded(ofSize size: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
        let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: weight)

        guard #available(iOS 13.0, *), let descriptor = systemFont.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) else { return systemFont }
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: size)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let label = UILabel()
label.font = .rounded(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Artem's answer:

```
extension UIFont {
    func rounded() -> UIFont {
        guard let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) else {
            return self
        }

        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

Now you can add `.rounded()` to any font to get its rounded variant if it exists.