# How to implement UIKit: SF Pro Rounded?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, storyboard, uikit

Help pls, I searched around and can't find the solution to implement this; [**Rounded**, The rounded variant of the default typeface.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor/systemdesign/3151800-rounded)

Here's the sample code

```swift
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 32)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
        label.font.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) // I'm guessing this is wrong

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Thanks

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961002/6561672

Comment: I can't get that one to work :/

Disclaimer: I'm new to Swift

Comment: I've posted answer on how to use that solution inside your code, try that:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well with the code from original answer ([How to use SF Rounded font in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550064/how-to-use-sf-rounded-font-in-swiftui/57961002#57961002)), you can use it in your code like this:

```
    override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 32)
    label.text = "Hello World!"
    label.textColor = .black

    // set rounded font
    let fontSize: CGFloat = 32
    let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .semibold)
    let roundedFont: UIFont
    if let descriptor = systemFont.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) {
        roundedFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: fontSize)
    } else {
        roundedFont = systemFont
    }

    label.font = roundedFont

    view.addSubview(label)
    self.view = view
}
```

But when you want to use it on multiple places, it would be better if you could reuse it... so for example I create class called FontKit ... which has static function, which gives me rounded font. Like this:

```
class FontKit {

 static func roundedFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
    let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: weight)
    let font: UIFont

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if let descriptor = systemFont.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) {
            font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: fontSize)
        } else {
            font = systemFont
        }
    } else {
        font = systemFont
    }

    return font
}
}
```

And then in my code I use it like this:

```
label.font = FontKit.roundedFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .semibold)
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is excellent! Aah, so both `systemFont` and `font` need to be a variable of type `UIFont`, did I get that right? and the _if statement_ is needed as a fallback for iOS versions that do not have a rounded alternative typeface? And I'm guessing you used _#available_ cause previous iOS version may not have _fontDescriptor_? So many things to learn, yikes! Feels so different from web dev.

Comment: Glad to hear that:)  Well this solution tries to be a really "safe" one. First of all, yes SF Pro rounded is available only on iOS 13. If you want to support earlier version with rounded font, I guess you should add custom rounded font . So that's reason why I use #available(iOS 13.0, *).  And just in case rounded description couldn't be found, there is fallback again, which returns plain system font.
So yeah, you always return UIFont type.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll only be using this for the system font, you can simplify it into the following:

```
public extension UIFont {
    
    var rounded: UIFont {
        guard let desc = self.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded)
        else { return self }
        return UIFont(descriptor: desc, size: self.pointSize)
    }
    
}
```

and then call it like:

```
let sysFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
label.font = sysFont.rounded
```

Calling it on any other font will just return the same font.